# Iterate over all pair combinations without repetition in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples, combinations

In haskell, given a list of elements, `xs`, the simplest way to iterate over all pair permutations with repetitions is:

```
[(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- xs]
```

I wish to be able to do the same, but only on combinations. If x and y were comparable, I could do

```
[(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- xs, x > y]
```

But I'd prefer a solution that is more generic and more efficient (I know that asympotitic complexity will remain squared, but we can halve actual runtime complexity by avoiding the usage of a filtering condition)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What about:

```
[ (x,y) | (x:rest) <- tails xs , y <- rest ]
```

Comment: That's short and sweet! The beauty of it is that you can extend it to however many elements you need, e.g for triplets `[(x,y,z)| (x:xrest) <- tails xs, (y:yrest)  <- tails xrest, z <- yrest]`

Answer (score 2):

If I copy and simplify `Math.Combinat.Sets.choose` for the particular case `k=2`, this gives

```
pairs :: [a] -> [[a]]
pairs []     = []
pairs (x:xs) = map (\y -> x:[y]) xs ++ pairs xs -- replace with \y -> (x,y) to get 2-tuples

>>> pairs [1,2,3]
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```