# Getting combination pairs of list elements

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to get all combinations of a list. The result for `[1,2,3]` should be `[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]`. My implementation below, however, gives `[(1,2),(2,3)]`.

```
parings [d] = []
parings (y:ys) = (y, head ys): parings ys
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191103/iterate-over-all-pair-combinations-without-repetition-in-haskell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're opposed to list comprehensions; with them, the solution is trivial:

```
pairwise :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairwise [] = []
pairwise (x:xs) = [(x, y) | y <- xs] ++ pairwise xs
```

You can factor out the comprehension into a separate function with explicit tail recursion if you want.

(The whole thing can be made tail-recursive, too, by keeping parameters for both sides of the `++` and having an accumulator parameter.)

Comment: awesome possum! And the reason for not using list comprehension is because I am challenging myself to learn algorithms and what goes through them internally. What if one day list comprehension breaks and we need to use normal algorithms haha i dont know im tired

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehension mentioned in 9000's answer can be trivially factored into a `map` call.

```
pairwise :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairwise [] = []
pairwise (x:xs) = map (\y -> (x, y)) xs ++ pairwise xs
```

Every list comprehension can be factored into some combination of `map`, `filter`, and `concatMap`, possibly with some `let` bindings interspersed. Doing so is a good exercise for learning how to manipulate functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one implementation using `tails` from `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List

pairings :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairings = concatMap makePairs . tails
    where
    makePairs [] = []
    makePairs (x:xs) = fmap ((,) x) xs
```

Notes:

- I don't know whether `tails` counts as a "special import" for you -- though it is not in the Prelude, it can be found in the *base* library, which is always available.
- To see what `tails` does, try `tails [1..3]`.
- `((,) x)` is just a compact way of writing `(\y -> (x, y))`. If you find it ugly, you can write the longer version instead, or enable the `TupleSections` extension and spell it as `(x,)`.
- `makePairs` might be written without explicit recursion as...

  ```
  makePairs = maybe [] (\(x, xs) -> fmap ((,) x) xs) . uncons
  ```

  ... with `uncons` also being found in `Data.List`.
- All the implementations in the answers here have a not insignificant problem: they retain consumed list segments in memory. To see what I'm talking about, watch the memory usage as you run `head . drop 8000000 $ pairings [1..]` in GHCi. I'm not confident about there being a workaround for that -- a simple `concat . tails`, for instance, appears to run into the same issue, while `fmap makePairs . tails` doesn't (even `head . drop (10^9) . head . drop (10^9) . fmap makePairs . tails $ [1..]` won't eat up all your memory).