# List of all element pairs using list monad in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I'm trying to make the function `pairs` that produces a list of all pairs of **different** elements in a given list, using the list monad. I would like to use `>>=` or `do` notation.

Here's what I have at this point:

```
pairs :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs xs = [ (x,y) | (x:rest) <- tails xs , y <- rest ]
```

Some examples:

- `pairs [1]` ==> `[]`
- `pairs [1,2]` ==> `[(1,2),(2,1)]`
- `pairs [1,2,3]` ==> `[(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)]`

I have read [Iterate over all pair combinations without repetition in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191103/iterate-over-all-pair-combinations-without-repetition-in-haskell)
.

Comment: @ErikCupal's answer should serve you well. `do` notation is not well loved and there are alternatives. One is this that does everything you want, even [x] = []. `f ls = [(a,b)| a<-ls,b<-ls, a/=b]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `do` notation:

```
pairs :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs xs = do
  a <- xs
  b <- xs
  if a == b
    then []
    else return (a, b)
```

and using `bind` (`>>=`):

```
pairs' :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs' xs =
  xs >>= \a ->
    xs >>= \b ->
      if a == b
        then []
        else [(a, b)]
```

Both of the solutions are equivalent. Do notation is just syntactic sugar for `>>=` chains.

Comment: Can also be written using `guard` from `Control.Monad`: `do { a <- xs; b <- xs; guard (a /= b); pure (a, b); }`