# list of all the possible pair of numbers in haskell

Tags: haskell

How to you write a function that gives a list of all the possible pairs of numbers from a list of numbers in haskell? for instance

[1, 7, 4]

gives

[(1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4)]

I've tried using zip like

```
numPairs :: [(Int, Int)]
numPairs
  = zip [1000..9999] [1000..9999]
```

but this didn't really work in the slightest.

Comment: Where is the list of input numbers?

Comment: I suspect it's the same task as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191103/iterate-over-all-pair-combinations-without-repetition-in-haskell